# Displaying remaining available products when mouse is hovering over the product image

Tags: magento-1.9, product

As I mentioned in the title, I want to display the remaining available products when the cursor is hovering over the product image.
To be more specific let's say that my product is a nike t-shirt, what I want is when the customer puts the cursor over the product image to appear a text box with the remaining available sizes, for example, sizes left: small, medium, large.
Is something like that possible, with the use of an extension, or doing it manually with code??

Comment: Do you want to show this in the product list or on a product detail page?

Comment: everywhere products appear except the product detail page, can that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't fully tested but the idea shuold work. Get all simple products from the config. Loop through and if it is in stock just echo the size. If all of this is in a div you can just show and hide it with js when the user does mouseover on the main image.

```
<div id="available-size">
<?php
$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null,$product);   
foreach($childProducts as $child) {

    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child->getId()); 
    $stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                                    ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
    if($stocklevel){
          echo $_product->getSize();
    }                    

}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: that's a good idea! i will add your code into list.phml and give you a feedback.

Comment: in the code sample above you forgot the php tags.

Comment: apologies - updated

Comment: I have putted the code in the list.phtml just below <?php if($hoverimage)?> but i didn't seem to change something on mouse hover..

Comment: well you need to do that in javascript and it's not exactly a magento question, it concerns the javascript functions show/hide . Are the sizes showing?

Comment: no i did not see the sizes anywhere in the page, i am saying that with the possibility of misplacing your code.

Comment: paste your full code up here in the question